# DecisionTreeRegressor ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a decision tree, and am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 5 and input n_features is 1.
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/content/Data.csv")
df.head()
y = df['CLASS']

X = df.drop(columns=['CLASS'])

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

my_tree = DecisionTreeRegressor()
my_tree.fit(X,y)
X_test = [[34],[62],[96],[30],[1]]

y_pred = my_tree.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)
```

Comment: The API says that the input needs to be of shape (n_samples, n_features).  X_test is shape (5,1).  The function is interpreting the input as 5 samples with 1 feature. You need to reshape X_test to conform to the intended shape.   https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html?highlight=decisiontreeregressor#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.fit

Comment: Try `X_test = np.array([34, 62, 96, 30, 1]).reshape(1, -1)`.